# Java StreamCorruptedException invalid stream header when initializing every other time

Tags: java, sockets, exception, inputstream

EDIT: I uploaded some sourcecode here: http://stabbedbit.com/MCapp/

I'm having the problem with my stream that the client throws a StreamCorruptedException every other time.

For example:

```
first time: works fine -> exit client application.
second time: StreamCorruptedException -> exit client application.
third time: works fine -> exit client application.
forth time: StreamCorruptedException -> exit client application.
```

and so forth.

Here's the story (in short)

The server while(true) loops for clients, accepts them and if an accepted client quits the server's inputStream throws a Socket Exception which I catch and use to run this bit code:

```
if(dataSender   != null) dataSender.stop();
if(dataReceiver != null) dataReceiver.stop();

try { if(output  != null) output    .close(); } catch(IOException e) { streamNotClosed("output"); }
try { if(input   != null) input     .close(); } catch(IOException e) { streamNotClosed("input"); }
try { if(cryptOut!= null) cryptOut  .close(); } catch(IOException e) { streamNotClosed("encrypted output"); }
try { if(cryptIn != null) cryptIn   .close(); } catch(IOException e) { streamNotClosed("encrypted input"); }
try { if(clientSocket != null) clientSocket.close(); }
catch(IOException e){ logger.warning(socketNotClosed); }
```

That all seems to work fine

The client and the server both use this bit of code for initializing streams:

```
cryptOut = new CipherOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), protocol.encoder);
output = new ObjectOutputStream(cryptOut);

cryptIn = new CipherInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream(), protocol.decoder);
input = new ObjectInputStream(cryptIn);
```

if all goes well a String is exchanged as handshake, the user gets verified and then input and output get forwarded to be handled by separate threads.

But when it doesn't the following error gets thrown at "input = new ObjectInputStream(cryptIn);"

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 81C69F13
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at com.stabbedbit.minecraftRemoteAdmin.desktop.connection.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

(The code it throws (81C69F13) is different every time)

I have tried solving this by calling the garbage collector when stopping the threads and closing the streams. But it without result. And I don't have any idea why else this could happening.

Edit: I also found out my server breaks if I connect a second client...

If anyone knows anything to help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try flushing output stream before reading back data

Comment: "if an accepted client quits the server's inputStream throws a Socket Exception".  Just a minute. It shouldn't do that. Throws what SocketException? What message?

Comment: @EJP it throws a **EOFException** because the stream gets cut off on the other side.

Comment: @BimaleshJha How can i flush a stream before initializing it?

Comment: @EJP I just remembered something: since I started closing the streams properly on the client it throws a **EOFException**. Before that it was always a SocketException when I closed the client.

Comment: If you get any IOException writing to a socket you must close it. EOFException is not a SocketException, and it does not occur when writing. Your question remains unclear.

Comment: @EJP the question is how to stop the streamcorruptedexception on the client's side from happening every other time.
The server is just handeling it okay.

Comment: @StabbedBit in your outputstream after you are done writing `flush()` the stream. Also check your Ciphers are properly initialized/reset in your code.

Comment: @BimaleshJha you sir, just solved my problem. I didn't re initialize my ciphers for every connection! Fixed that and no errors anywhere now. I feel stupid... If you want write that down as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised, and specifically because the solution turned out to have nothing to so with the question or title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outputstream after you are done writing, flush() the stream. Also, check your Ciphers are properly initialized/reset in your code

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to close the ObjectOutputStream code;
out.close();

Comment: That wouldn't explain why a stream header is invalid.